# Can I launch a process as root without launching root's login shell?

Tags: login, root

I tried to change the login shell.

Here's what the first line of `/etc/passwd` looks like (on a Debian Wheezy install):

```
rootx:0:0:root:/root:/:zsh
```

When I try to login as `root`:

```
Cannot execute zsh: No such file or directory
```

I know `zsh` is available:

```
$ which zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

Okay, it seems logical to replace `zsh` by its full path. But how can I do it?

I have one other user on the system (`user`), however it doesn't have root privileges and `sudo` is not installed on the system.

Assume that for whatever reason (encryption, physical access, ...) I cannot boot on a live CD to modify the file.

I do know, however, the credentials for the `root` account.

My question is: Is there any way, even programatically, to launch a process with the `root` account without launching its login shell first?

Comment: what about `su`? or `gksu`? something like `su -c 'sed -i s,root:/:zsh,root:/:/usr/bin/zsh, /etc/passwd'`

Comment: Shouldn't the line the passwd file been /usr/bin/zsh? Why did you put just the string zsh?

Comment: @slm That's the change the OP wants to make...

Comment: The *easiest* way to fix this might be to boot the system from a live CD, mount the root partition, and edit /etc/passwd on it through there. It's the approach I would take to fixing this issue, if a reboot is acceptable.

Comment: @qdii: `Cannot execute zsh`.

Comment: if @qdii suggestion works (i.e. that `su -c "<commands>"` )work... could we not then simply use `su -c "/bin/bash"` to get to a working bash with user **root**?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: that's not supposed to work. The command passed to `-c` is run via the user's login shell. `-s` can be used to use another shell... only if the existing login shell is valid or the invoker is root.

Answer (score 4):

#### Have su permissions

You can use the following command to change any users' shell.

```
su -c "/usr/bin/chsh -s /bin/bash root"
```

#### If you have physical access

During your Grub boot you can get into any system so long as you have console access and there isn't a password preventing you from gaining access to the Grub menu.

During the initial boot up of the system when the Grub menu shows up, if you enter the menu and edit (press <kbd>e</kbd> key) the kernel line, you can add one of the following things to make the kernel boot in single user mode.

- single
- init=/bin/sh
- 1

The line will look something like this:

```
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.15-27-386 root=/dev/mapper/Ubuntu-root ro init=/bin/bash
```

In Grub it should look similar to this:

[image: ss of grub]

Once you've made the changes boot the kernel (press key <kbd>b</kbd>).

This will give you temporary access to the system with a shell where you can use vi/vim to make whatever changes you need to your `/etc/passwd` file. Just type `reboot` when you're done.

Comment: He says he doesn't have physical access, thus likely he won't be able to see the GRUB menu.

Comment: @Renan. OK I didn't get that from the first few reads. It's hidden in the line about the "..I cannot boot on a live CD.." which is phrased strangely to me.

Comment: Your `su` command won't work, since it'll try to invoke root's shell, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Gilles: Got any other ideas? I'm not seeing a way to fix this without physical access then. Feel like we're working against exactly what the system was designed to prevent at this point.

Comment: @slm Without sudo, I think the root account is locked, so physical access is required.

Comment: @Gilles Agreed. The only other methods I can think of are nefarious ways, like exploiting a cron that he may know about to get injected a new `/etc/passw`d file into the system. I think you're out of luck w/o physical access as well!

Comment: If I have time later tonight, I'll try a couple of other things with a spare VM, but don't hold your breath!

Comment: Great, this worked but I had to change from "ro" read-only to "rw" to make any changes using vim. Thanks!

Comment: @erran - makes sense.